# Symfony2 Doctrine indexes using YAML

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Because documentation on YAML in Doctrine isn't really informative, I was trying to create indexes for few (already existing) tables from exaple codes. I put some additional lines to my *.orm.yml files, but after calling `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` and `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get a message that my database is already in sync.That's kind of problematic - I'm not an expert in Symfony nor database management at all, but as far as I know indexing your tables is kind of crucial when I use queries a lot, mostly searching by values from one column of a table, ain't I right? So please, help me to create indexes via Symfony/Doctrine using YAML, I have no idea what more I can do.

Here's one of my .orm.yml files:

```
Sc0\LoginBundle\Entity\LoginDictionary:
  type: entity
  table: login_dictionary
  indexes:
    login_dictionary_index:
      columns: [ name ]

  id:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 30

  fields:
    polish:
      type: string
      length: 150
      nullable: false
```

If it's important I'm using PostgreSQL for database management. Maybe I should just create standard indexes using normal postgres queries? Will Symfony 'see' those indexes created manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `name` is a primary key there is already an index for this column. You can check with PHPMyAdmin. That's why you have the message that the  database is already synced: an index is already present.

Comment: Sothere is no point adding this 'indexes:' part for me? Indexes are created by default for primary keys, so if my queries here always looks like `SELECT polish FROM login_dictionary WHERE name=whatever` there is no speed boost possible, right?
I just want to make sure - when indexes are really needed?

Comment: No there is already an index, so adding `indexes:` will do nothing, as described in your question (*Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata*). About performance, I'm sorry but I don't know. But I know that if you want to perform join operations you should use an integer as the primary key in order to use it as a foreign key in other tables. An integer is more efficient than a string as an index.

Comment: No joins will ever be needed, at least for this table, as it's just a dictionary. For all others, more important tables, I have an integer `id` field. I just want my tables be well designed and I've heard many times that indexing your tables is important, because it improves speed of query execution. Thanks for your help!